# JPanel above JLabel using Layered Panes

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jlayeredpane

I have a JPanel that contains a bunch of small icons, and a JLabel containing a bigger icon.

First of all, I need clarification on something. By not setting `panel.isOpaque`, the said `panel` would have a transparent background and would properly overlap the icons of my JPanel and JLabel. Is this true?

Now to my problem. I've been following the LayeredPanes tutorial on the Oracle website, and I can't seem to make it right on my case.

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    ImageIcon underIcon;
    URL urlUnder = myClass.class.getResource("images/underImage.gif");
    underIcon = new ImageIcon(urlUnder);
    JLabel labelUnder = new JLabel(underIcon);

    ImageIcon panelIcon;
    URL urlAbove = myClass.class.getResource("images/aboveImage.gif");
    panelIcon = new ImageIcon(urlAbove);
    JLabel aboveIcon1 = new JLabel(panelIcon);
    JLabel aboveIcon2 = new JLabel(panelIcon);

    JPanel panelAbove = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panelAbove.setOpaque(false);
    panelAbove.add(aboveIcon1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panelAbove.add(aboveIcon2, BorderLayout.EAST);

    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();

    layeredPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    layeredPane.add(labelUnder, BorderLayout.CENTER, 1);
    layeredPane.add(panelAbove, BorderLayout.CENTER, 2);

    layeredPane.setOpaque(true);

    window.setContentPane(layeredPane);

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
```

I only see the contents of the panel. And I'm 100% sure the images are there on `getResource`, so that's not the issue. Please advice on how to properly use Layered Panes.

Comment: are you using an IDE and, if so, which one? I've experienced a similar problem recently and may be able to help.

Comment: @JeremyJohnson: I'm using Netbeans atm.

Comment: Have you set the "images" folder as a source folder?

Comment: If you wish to vote down this question, please give the OP an explanation as well. Down-votes alone are not going to prevent behavior you disapprove of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are setting a layout manager to the `JLayeredPane`

```
layeredPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

In of it self, this is not a problem, but your choice of layout manager is.

`BorderLayout` will only a single componet to occupy any of it's 5 predefined positions.  This means when you add your second component, it, effectively, replaces the first.

Try using someone like `GridBagLayout` instead. Providing a single `GridBagConstaint` set so that the `weightx/y` values ara equal to `1`, the fill property is set to `BOTH` and it's `gridx/y` properties are set to `0`

Unlike `BorderLayout`, `GridBagLayout` will allow you to layout components to the same position

Comment: I see. I was just honestly guessing to see if it will work. I'll check out `GridBagLayout` (haven't messed with it yet) and come back for more feedback.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html):

```
layeredPane.add(dukeLabel, new Integer(2), 0);
```

> This code uses the three-argument version of the add method. The third argument specifies the Duke label position within its depth, which determines the component's relationship with other components at the same depth.
>
> Positions are specified with an int between -1 and (n - 1), where n is the number of components at the depth. Unlike layer numbers, the smaller the position number, the higher the component within its depth. **Using -1 is the same as using n - 1; it indicates the bottom-most position. Using 0 specifies that the component should be in the top-most position within its depth.** As the following figure shows, with the exception of -1, a lower position number indicates a higher position within a depth.

So your depth orders are the wrong way around, also start from 0.

I also found this in the [Solving Common Component Problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/problems.html#layeredpane) Section

> Problem: The components in my layered pane are not layered correctly. In fact, the layers seem to be inversed — the lower the depth the higher the component.
>
> This can happen if you use an int instead of an Integer when adding components to a layered pane. To see what happens, in the LayeredPaneDemo class, change

```
layeredPane.add(label, new Integer(i));
```

to

```
layeredPane.add(label, i);.
```

Comment: This wasn't the exact problem, but thank you for pointing out this mistake as well.